# Glade instance has no attribute

Tags: python, button, click, instance, glade

Good day everyone,

I am currently working in Glade to build a GUI for a program that I have already written. I have the window set up and running properly, and am now trying to create defs for the button clicks to start executing my code. I keep getting the following error code however:

```
glade.py:17: RuntimeWarning: missing handler 'on_button4_clicked'
self.builder.connect_signals(self) 
glade.py:17: RuntimeWarning: missing handler 'on_button1_clicked'
self.builder.connect_signals(self)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "glade.py", line 31, in <module>
main = mainClass()
File "glade.py", line 21, in __init__
dic = { "on_button4_clicked" : self.button4_clicked}
AttributeError: mainClass instance has no attribute 'button4_clicked'
```

Here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class mainClass:

    def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_gtk_quit_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.gladefile = "pyhelloworld.glade"
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
        self.window.show()

    dic = { "on_button4_clicked" : self.button4_clicked}

    self.wTree.signal_autoconnect(dic)

    def button4_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
main = mainClass()
gtk.main()
```

I have not attached my .glade code because it is rather long (is there a way to attach it in a zip file or something) Looking at it though, I made sure to set clicked button signal, and here is the portion that states that:

```
<object class="GtkButton" id="button4">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">VDBench Right Slot</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<signal name="clicked" handler="on_button4_clicked" swapped="no"/>
```

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it, as I am fairly new to python and even newer to GUI design. Thanks

Comment: The python error sounds like it is pointing to an error in your code, not the gladefile. Are you sure that the button4_clicked method is a class method in mainClass?

Comment: Also, pay attention to those RuntimeWarnings stating that you are missing handlers...there is clearly some code you have left out of the sample above containing a reference to a missing on_button1_clicked handler as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need the call to

```
self.wTree.signal_autoconnect(dic)
```

if instead you declare this dictionary in your **init**() method

```
signal_dictionary = {"on_button4_clicked" : self.button4_clicked}
```

before you call

```
self.builder.connect_signals(signal_dictionary)
```

If you define all of your glade signals >>> python method mappings in the `signal_dictionary` dictionary ahead of time, it should work. I am not sure that it is necessary to connect your signals upon creation of the class like this, but in general I think it is good practice to.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. by moving the def of the button to before the dictionary and connect_signals, it is running properly now. Thanks for your assistance here is the final code now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class mainClass:
    def button1_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello World!" 
    def button2_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello World!" 
    def button3_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello World!" 
    def button4_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello World!" 
    def button5_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello World!" 
    def button6_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello World!" 


    def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_gtk_quit_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):

        self.gladefile = "pyhelloworld.glade"
        signal_dictionary = { "on_button1_clicked" : self.button1_clicked,
                      "on_button2_clicked" : self.button2_clicked,
                      "on_button3_clicked" : self.button3_clicked,
                      "on_button4_clicked" : self.button4_clicked, 
                      "on_button5_clicked" : self.button5_clicked, 
                      "on_button6_clicked" : self.button6_clicked} 
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(signal_dictionary)
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
        self.window.show()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = mainClass()
    gtk.main()
```